# Updating TypeScript version

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I run `npm install -g typescript` to update my `TypeScript` version globally, but when I run `ng v` in my `Angular` project, I still see an old version. Why is that? How can I consistently upgrade this?

[image]

Comment: Do you have TypesScript installed as a dependency within your Angular project?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can run the below code to upgrade the version of your current project

```
npm i typescript@next -D
```

Comment: that works.  it can also give you a dev version.

Comment: `typescript@next` install the latest pre-release version of TS. This means that you will get the most recent version of TypeScript that is not yet stable. Use `@latest` instead

Answer (score 6):

To upgrade the typescript version of your Angular project to the **latest stable** version, use :

```
npm i typescript@latest --save-dev
```

You can verify the upgrade in your `package.json` file :

```
"devDependencies": {
    // ...
    "typescript": "^5.2.2" // typescript current installed version
}
```